# Geometric Distribution: Number expected until the first defective

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> An industrial process manufactures components with a 10% defective
>   rate. Each day the process is subjected to a quality control
>   inspection; products are inspected sequentially until the ﬁrst
>   defective is obtained. What is the number of inspections expected until the ﬁrst defective?

My answer is $1/p$ which is $\frac1{0.1} = 10$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, we need $10$ inspections in the average.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   Well, a full answer is: "The count of inspections until the first defective has a *geometric distribution* with 'success' rate $1/10$, therefore the expected count is $10$."

[Naked numbers won't get full marks in an exam or interview; include your reasoning as much as possible.]